# Missing required icon file - exactly 120x120, 76X76, etc... Attempted solutions but no success

Tags: xcode, icons, itunes-store

So I've recently redesigned the UI of one of my apps, which I'm looking to update. As a finishing touch, I've also redone the app icon for iPhone and iPad. Like the first time, I used a mac app Asset Catalog Creator and Prepo or websites like MakeAppIcon.com and AppIcon.build, or some other closely related online app to create Homescreen and other icons. Typically, these are successful right off the bat. Unfortunately, after a number of failed attempts, as soon as I try to "validate", I receive several errors regarding missing icons.

[image]

I've used the mentioned apps and websites several times in the hopes of some success... no avail. I've tried adding the individual files directly from Sketch, with no luck. I even added each item in my assets in the info.plist and I'm still receiving the same errors. I am unsure how to proceed and would greatly appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a week of frustration, it would seem all I had to do was select my project and under the "genera" tab, look for the "App Icons and Launch Images" section, and select the "App Icons Source" to "Use Asset Catalog." From there, I was able to simply drag and drop the images created from my icon generator and drop them into one of the icon image spots. From here, all you have to worry about is adding any extra images the generator may not have automatically created.